# How to Create a Service in Angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

plunkr:
http://embed.plnkr.co/qJWWRW/

I want to make the "dialogService" available to all/specific controllers in my app. I stopped at the last running version in the plunkr. What I thought I need to do, but which didn't work is:

1) Change (app.js):

```
myAppServices.controller('dialogService' ...
```

to

```
myAppServices.service('dialogService'
```

2) Add a dependency to MainCtrl (app.js):

```
myAppControllers.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$cookies', '$location', 'dialogService',
  function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $cookies, $location, dialogService) {
    this.log = function(log) {
```

Questions:
1) Where am I wrong
2) In the service customDialogCtrl is used, do I have to make it a service too?
EDIT:
According to this article (https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make) it maybe anyways a bad idea to structure by type. Instead I will group by function. It also broadened my understanding. So each model needs a dependency on the others, if it uses s.th. from the other model.

I tried to work according to this tutorial but I have my controllers in a separate file. I load all the controllers with my dependency on the controller variable.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/ (STEP 5)

Comment: Can you describe what is the intended behaviour you want for the dialog service?

Comment: It should open an exit modal on any view to get feedback. Also I may use later the other modal functions to display alerts, notifications or feedback if certain elements are used etc. 

So in the first stage I only need it on certain views/controllers but later I may need it on the whole application. But anyways my application is wrapped within the main controller so it would be Ok if the MainCtrl has access.

PS: The modal code is not mine I just adjusted it to my needs

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution now. I think I had a misunderstanding of services. I removed all scope variables. Defined a variable

```
thisService = this;
```

Used this instead. Inside the service functions I needed to pass this variable.

```
myDialog.service('dialogService',['$http','$timeout','dialogs',function($http,$timeout,dialogs){
    var thisService =this;
    thisService.message={};
    thisService.errors={};
    thisService.sucess=false;

    this.sendFeedback = function(name,email, thisService) {
      $http({
            url: 'php/log.php',
            method: "POST",
            // withCredentials: true,
            // headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            data: {   what: 'feedback',
                      name: name,
                      email: email
                    }
          }).success(function(data, thisService) {

              if (!data.success) {
                // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                thisService.errors= data.errors;
              } else {
                // if successful, bind success message to message
                thisService.message= data.message;
                thisService.sucess=true;
              }
            });
    };

    this.launch = function(which){
      switch(which){
        case 'error':
          dialogs.error();
          break;
        case 'notify':
          dialogs.notify();
          break;
        case 'confirm':
          var dlg = dialogs.confirm();
          dlg.result.then(function(btn){
            // this.confirmed = 'You confirmed "Yes."';
          },function(btn){
            // this.confirmed = 'You confirmed "No."';
          });
          break;
        case 'custom':
          var dlg = dialogs.create('/dialogs/custom.html','customDialogCtrl',{},{size:'lg',keyboard: true,backdrop: true,windowClass: 'my-class'});
          dlg.result.then(function(user){
            thisService.sendFeedback(user.name,user.email);
            dialogs.notify('Nachricht gesendet', 'Wir haben Deine Anfrage erhalten');
          },function(){
            //if nothing do xy

          });
          break;
      }
    }; // end launch



  }]);

  myDialog.controller('customDialogCtrl',function($scope,$modalInstance,data){
    //-- Variables --//

    $scope.user = {name : ''};
    $scope.user = {email : ''};


    //-- Methods --//

    $scope.cancel = function(){
      $modalInstance.dismiss('Canceled');
    }; // end cancel

    $scope.save = function(){
      $modalInstance.close($scope.user);
    }; // end save

    $scope.hitEnter = function(evt){
      if(angular.equals(evt.keyCode,13) && !(angular.equals($scope.user.name,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.name,'')) && !(angular.equals($scope.user.email,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.email,''))){
        console.log(!(angular.equals($scope.user.name,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.name,'')));
        console.log(!(angular.equals($scope.user.email,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.email,'')));
        $scope.save();}
      else
      {console.log(!(angular.equals($scope.user.name,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.name,'')));
        console.log(!(angular.equals($scope.user.email,null) || angular.equals($scope.user.email,'')));}
    };
  }); // end controller(customDialogCtrl)

  // .run(function($templateCache){
  //   $templateCache.put('/dialogs/custom.html','<div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> User\'s Name</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><ng-form name="nameDialog" novalidate role="form"><div class="form-group input-group-lg" ng-class="{true: \'has-error\'}[nameDialog.username.$dirty && nameDialog.username.$invalid]"><label class="control-label" for="course">Name:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" ng-model="user.name" ng-keyup="hitEnter($event)" required><span class="help-block">Enter your full name, first &amp; last.</span></div></ng-form></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="(nameDialog.$dirty && nameDialog.$invalid) || nameDialog.$pristine">Save</button></div>');
  // });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you first need to understand is the difference between a Service, a Controller and a Directive and how and when to use them.

#### Controller

You use a controller to wire up services, dependencies and other complex logic and assign them to the scope of your view. A very simple example of why or when you should use a controller is, for example, in a view where you want to initialize your model to something specific:

```
angular.module('App',[]).controller('BasicCtrl', function(){
   this.myModel = { name: "foo" };
});
```

#### Service

You can and should use a service when you either a) have some logic that you want to apply or reuse in multiple parts of your application and b) want to pass some data across multiple controllers. For example, I can create a service that acts as a data store and share it on all my controllers:

```
angular.module("App",[]).service("DataService", function(){
     var data = [];

     return {
          add: function(item) {
              data.push(item);
          },
          getAllData: function() {
              return data;
          }
     }
}
```

On every controller you inject this service you'll have access to the `data` array, and can reuse it.

#### Directive

A directive should be used when you want to interact with the DOM and as such, is also a good way of dealing with interactions from the user with the page. For example, imagine I want to add in my app a button that logs feedback from the user. I can do that by just adding to my page:

```
<feedback-button feedback-type="custom"></feedback-button>
```

And all the logic should be in that directive:

```
dialogModule.directive('feedbackButton', function(dialogs, $http){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    template: '<button class="btn btn-warning">Custom Dialog</button>',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      scope.feedback = {};
      scope.user = {name : ''};
      scope.email = {email : ''};

      scope.sendFeedback = function() {
        $http({
          url: 'php/log.php',
          method: "POST",
          // withCredentials: true,
          // headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
          data: {   what: 'feedback',
                    name: scope.feedback.name,
                    email: scope.feedback.email
                  }
        }).success(function(data) {
          scope.message = null;
          scope.feedbackErrorName = null;
          scope.feedbackErrorEmail = null;
          // console.log(data);
          if (!data.success) {
            // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
              scope.feedbackErrorName = data.errors.name;
              scope.feedbackErrorEmail = data.errors.email;
          } else {
            // if successful, bind success message to message
              scope.message = data.message;
              scope.feedback.show=false;
          }
        });
      }

      scope.launch = function(which){
        switch(which){
          case 'error':
            dialogs.error();
            break;
          case 'notify':
            dialogs.notify();
            break;
          case 'confirm':
            var dlg = dialogs.confirm();
            dlg.result.then(function(btn){
              scope.confirmed = 'You confirmed "Yes."';
            },function(btn){
              scope.confirmed = 'You confirmed "No."';
            });
            break;
          case 'custom':
            var dlg = dialogs.create('custom.html','customDialogCtrl',{},{size:'lg',keyboard: true,backdrop: true,windowClass: 'my-class'});
            dlg.result.then(function(user){
              console.log(user);
              console.log(user.email);
              scope.feedback.name = user.name;
              scope.feedback.email = user.email;
              scope.sendFeedback();
            },function(){
              if(angular.equals(scope.feedback.name,''))
                scope.feedback.name = 'You did not enter in your name!';
                scope.feedback.email = 'You did not enter your email!';
            });
            break;
        }
      };

      element.on('click', function(){
        scope.launch(attributes['feedbackType']);
      });
    } 
  }

});
```

Here's a working plunker (I've changed it a bit in relation to yours):
http://plnkr.co/edit/7ECkZhW4BxFUMiclU23m?p=preview

Edit: Just wanted to add that this code could be refactored and the sendFeedback method should probably be moved into a service, since the type of functionality (interacting with a backend server) is more appropriate to be in a service than in a directive.